# Display Domain suggestions having keywords appended in suggestions - WHMCS domain checker

Tags: whmcs

I'm working on WHMCS Latest Version 7. On submitting domain checker form, usually we get the domain availability information and domain suggestions with other extensions. For example: If we search for example.com, We will get a set of suggestions as follows.

1. example.net
2. example.org

I need another set of suggestions with some set of words appended with the keyword user selected as follows

1. theexmaple.net
2. myexample.net
3. exmapleonline.net
4. theexmaple.org
5. myexample.org
6. exmapleonline.org

Answer (score 0):

Domain suggestions are implemented by Domain Registrar modules. You can use eNom or ResellerClub for their built in suggestions. Both of those will attempt to use related words in the name to get a better suggestion. If you want behavior exactly like you described, you can write a custom domain registrar module that adds the common prefixes and suffixes you're interested in and then returns results.

http://developers.whmcs.com/domain-registrars/availability-checks/